# Is it possible to tell if you were redirected to an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, url

I am redirecting users to a specific page based on some criteria. I know I can pass some url parameters indicating that there was a redirect. But is there any other way to tell it without turning to the url string?

Comment: have you tried sending a redirect response to the server using an HTTP response code in the 300s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing an actual redirect then yes, a redirect is a specific HTTP response code to the browser.  Usually a HTTP 301 or 302 response code; these tell the browser to make another request to the server for the URL provided in the response.

This is different than using something like a `Server.Transfer` or some sort of URL rewriting technique, which can make the "redirection" completely transparent to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Server.Transfer](http://dotnetperls.com/server-transfer) could be used to pass along a request without updating the Querystring, though this does carry some limitations as it isn't a perfect solution.